# It is necessary to start route name [splash_screen] with a slash: /splash_screen Flutter

Tags: flutter

I am new to flutter. Searched everything over internet but not able to find solution.

Getting this error when I am running app

```
 It is necessary to start route name [splash_screen] with a slash: /splash_screen
 'package:get/get_navigation/src/routes/get_route.dart':
 Failed assertion: line 70 pos 16: 'name.startsWith('/')'
```

Here is main.dart code:-

```
 initialRoute: Routes.splashScreen,
```

And this is in routes.dart:-

```
  static final String splashScreen = "splash_screen";
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems this is a common mistake, if you are using OnGenerate and the named route you have to start with the "/pagename" manner so it should be like this

```
static final String splashScreen = "/splash_screen";
```

If this is your first page just do this one :

```
static final String splashScreen = "/";
```

Comment: I tried this also, But its not working. Getting same error.

Comment: Ok so is this your first page after app opening right

Comment: Check the edit as it is the first route then you can only add the "/". Let me know if it works

Comment: Got the problem, Needs to add slash in every route, Then clean flutter for picking changes, Then needs to rebuild. After that its working fine.

Comment: That's awesome flutter people often forget to rebuild the app, to much used to the hot reload feature. Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

You need to write: `static final String splashScreen = "/"`

Answer (score 0):

For naming convention flutter uses Camel case standard like- `camel_case`
and for Directory/package name- `camelCase`